# How to record Audio using Microphone in AAC codec format

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, gstreamer

How to record Audio using Microphone in AAC codec format in mp4 file using gstreamer ?

Please reply with pipeline info.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If your default audio source is Microphone, then you can try

```
gst-launch autoaudiosrc ! audioconvert ! faac ! mp4mux ! filesink location=aac_audio.mp4
```

However if you have multiple audio sources and mic is not default audio source, then you have to specify device identifier of the mic input. Plus you need to know whether you have ALSA or OSS driver. 
My suggestion would be to try

```
gst-launch alsa-src device=<device identifier for mic input> ! audioconvert ! faac ! mp4mux ! filesink location=aac_audio.mp4
```

or

```
gst-launch oss-src device=<device identifier for mic input> ! audioconvert ! faac ! mp4mux ! filesink location=aac_audio.mp4
```

depending on which driver you have.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Could u please tell that how I can check which driver I have and the device name?

Comment: @oak Bytes What is the identifier corresponding the Microphone?